# Break write permission for non root user?

Tags: permissions, files, security, non-root-user

Can non root user edit files he/she doesn't have access to or create new a file in a directory he/she doesn't own? Is there a way to do that?

**P.S :** I know if root user or file owner gives him write permission he would be able to. I'm asking if he can't be granted permission.

In other words, can Linux permissions be hacked?

Comment: Social engineering is the way to go.  Find a PHP admin with root access and tell him `chmod -R 0777 /` will fix his problem.

Comment: Don't you say :P

Comment: Don't you think if the answer were yes, they would fix that really fast to make the answer no? Maybe I'm still not understanding the question

Comment: you may feel it's a dump question but I really wanted to know if that is possible or not .

Comment: Of course it can be hacked; this is not a useful question.

Comment: well , I'm asking to know ! what's wrong in that ? 
couldn't find any Web page tells me about this and I was curious about it . Thanks . delete my question admins to let the world rests in peace  !

Answer (score 2):

If you have physical access to the box, boot off a live distro, mount the target filesystem and chroot into it. Keep your white hat on, though.

Note that this won't work if your admin was careful enough to set a BIOS password.